# Can OpenCV capture image from Microsoft Surface Pro camera?

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

Basically, I have a prototype ready with OpenCV that captures images from connected webcams. We need to ship it to customers and they include Surface Pro users, which has an integrated rear camera.

I am not sure whether it would work on that device or not i.e. whether my code would detect the integrated Surface Pro camera or not. We currently do not have access to such a machine.

So, is there a way validate this? I can think of two options:

1. Is there any emulator available for Surface Pro camera?
2. Does OpenCV provide a list of cameras which it supports?

Would really appreciate any form of assistance here!

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV works via the OS camera drivers. If the Surface Pro camera appears as a normal camera to Windows OpenCV should see it as just another camera.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs! How can I validate the if part i.e. 'if Surface Pro camera appears as a normal camera to Windows'?

Comment: @Sankalp Buy/borrow/otherwise gain access to a working MS Surface Pro. Especially when that's one of your target platforms (and you have some concerns).

Answer (score 0):

For record's sake - This [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17243170/380316) gives the code for iterating available devices.

And personally I can verify that OpenCV works with the Surface Pro cameras (front and rear). We are using the EMGU port of it.