# Is using DirectShowNET Library still the best way to get all connected camera devices for videocapture?

Tags: c#

Answers to the question "How to get a list of all cameras (USB, IP, build-in) for capture" are all answered by pointing to [DirectShowNet](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net). 
However all these entries ([here's the most prominent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169430/set-capture-device-emgucv)) I could find are several years old, the library itself seems quite a bit old. Therefore my rather simple question: is the a better, more convenient way now, or is this still the way to go?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/CaptureEngineVideoCapture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around this topic in different forums, I found that using WMI is the best approach to solve this. 
[With the help of this article I managed to adapt code snippets to the following simple method, which works perfectly in my case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/connecting-to-wmi-remotely-with-c-):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// uses WMI to get all available cameras and add them to the list
    /// </summary>
    private void GetAvailableCameraList()
    {
        AvailableCameras = new List<string>();
        string wmiQuery = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPSignedDriver");

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
        ManagementObjectCollection retObjectCollection = searcher.Get();

        foreach (var WmiObject in retObjectCollection)
        {
                if (WmiObject["DeviceClass"] != null && WmiObject["DeviceClass"].ToString().Equals("IMAGE"))
                {
                    AvailableCameras.Add(WmiObject["DeviceName"].ToString());
                }
        }
    }
```